# Gfortran does not compile a simple 'hello world' program

Tags: fortran, gfortran

i have a problem that is driving me crazy. I just did a clean installation of UBUNTU 18.04 LTS and installed VS Code and gfortran-9 successfully. The problem is that i can't compile a simple hello world program.

The file is saved as hello.f90 and i tried to compile it in several ways, like:

```
`gfortran-9 hello.f90 -o hello.exe

`gfortran-9 hello.exe
```

or using object file. I always end up with the same error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the code is simply:

```
program hello
implicit none
print *, 'hello world'
end program hello
```

I searched everywhere on the internet, but since i'm new to ubuntu when it comes to solution like: "installing libraries", or similar i just can't go on without anyone who explain me step by step...I hope in you.

Comment: Welcome. I suggest to take the Welcome [tour].

Comment: How did you install gfortran.  Just curious because it is normally called gfortran: not gfortran-9.

Comment: I simply used sudo apt-get install gfortran-9. But in any case i even installed just gfortran. The error remain the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Basically i was trying to execute the executable with the command `gfortran namefile.exe` but then i realised that maybe i should've used the command `./namefile.exe` and in fact it worked. So the compiling process was good, it was me who was wrong in the execution.

Comment: In that case PTRK was right but your description was confusing. Are you sure it really gave you the `undefined reference to `main'` error? I would not expect that one because the compiled program does contain `main`.

Comment: The problem was that i was trying to "compile" an executable file, because i thought that the command to execute was `gfortran namefile.exe` . If you try to do that you get the error that i posted in the question. I'm sure of that because i tried to do the same thing with another pc with 18.04 and the result was the same. But to be honest i don't know why it says "undefined reference to main" instead of "impossible to compile a .exe file"